# What means => used in this way in Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I searched something on SO and run into this, which is a way to retrive a file from your local computer and use it in browser, with AngularJS.

```
this.http.get(<path_to_your_json_file>)
 .success((data) => console.log(data));
```

I wonder what this JavaScript syntax could mean:

> (data) => console.log(data)

I don't know if is something AngularJS specific, but I mostly doubt so. Do you know more interesting tweaks which are no so common in daily use of JavaScript?

Comment: It's called an arrow function. They are very common in ES6.

Comment: It's called the final nail in internet explorer coffin

Comment: It can't be used in internet explorer?

Comment: Internet Explorer is too old to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Arrow functions were introduced into JavaScript with ES2015.

Writing `(data) => console.log(data)` is equivalent to writing `function (data) { console.log(data); }`.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).